# How to add row of total and percentage in list of data table in R?

Tags: r, list

I have a list of a data table that wants two rows 1. total  2. percentage for each data table.
Here just added a sample.  what I want to add the fourth row of totals to sum the columns y and z, not PROVINCE and the fifth row of percentage.

```
#> [[1]]
#>   PROVINCE         Y        Z
#> 1        2  89.98376 90.79929
#> 2        2  97.12802 90.68774
#> 3        4 100.62682 91.20288
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   PROVINCE         Y         Z
#> 1        4 106.09127  94.19237
#> 2        6 111.30426 107.42695
#> 3        5  84.44623 102.04221
```

Answer (score 2):

You could opt for a construct like:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!C:C,MATCH(MID($A2,IFERROR(FIND("|",$A2)+1,1),LEN($A2)),Sheet1!$B:$B,0))
```

Use that formula in `Sheet2!B2`. Drag down and into column `C:C`.

Comment: It just works for the name column. when I concatenate column List and name between them I use (|). C column must ignore the first part of the cell just match with name column value. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Since you haven't provided actual markdown sample data I went with an untested formula. It should do exactly what you described it should do. It will try to find the position of the pipe symbol as a starting point for `MID`. If not found, start from 1st position. @Samira.